# Saving data to Two db tables with two models inYii

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I'm attempting to save data to two db tables with two different models in Yii.  I've consulted the wiki: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/ and http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/52109-save-data-with-two-models/, yet I still can't get the data to save to both tables. I have two  tables `sales_rep_min_margin` and `sales_rep_min_margin_history`:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales_rep_min_margin` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`domestic` int(2) NOT NULL,
`overseas` int(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​​​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-​-

History table:

```
  CREATE TABLE `sales_rep_min_margin_history` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `min_margin_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `from` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `update_username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `update_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `min_margin_id` (`min_margin_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `sales_rep_min_margin_history_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`min_margin_id`) REFERENCES `sales_rep_min_margin` (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

My SalesRepMinMarginController code (right now) is: 
public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new SalesRepMinMargin;
        $model2 = new SalesRepMinMarginHistory;

        //Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        //$this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if (isset($_POST['SalesRepMinMargin'])) {

            $model->attributes = $_POST['SalesRepMinMargin'];

            if ($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
        if (isset($_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory'])) {

            $model2->attributes = $_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory'];
            $model2->save();

            $this->render('create', array(
                'model' => $model,
            ));
        }
    }

and 'SalesRepMinMarginHistoryController':
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory'];

        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

I just need to save the data to the tables, but I don't need the 'history' table's data in the view.  Any help is greatly aprreciated!  Someone offered me the following code, however, it's not working:

```
public function actionCreate() {

    $model = new SalesRepMinMargin;
    $model2 = new SalesRepMinMarginHistory;

    //Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    //$this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if (isset($_POST['SalesRepMinMargin'])) {

        $model->attributes = $_POST['SalesRepMinMargin'];

        if ($model->save()) {

            if (isset($_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory'])) {

                $model2->attributes = $_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory'];
                $model2->save();
            }

            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model, 'model2' => $model2,
        ));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all save data in first table using model

```
$model = new SalesRepMinMargin;
$model->attributes = $_POST['SalesRepMinMargin'];
if($model->save(false)) {
    /* use second model */
    $model2 = new SalesRepMinMarginHistory;
    $model2->attributes = $_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory'];
    $model2->save();
    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is the second model, does any of this need to be changed?  
 public function actionCreate()
 {
  $model=new SalesRepMinMarginHistory;

  // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
  // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

  if(isset($_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory']))
  {
   $model->attributes=$_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory'];
   if($model->save())
    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
  }

  $this->render('create',array(
   'model'=>$model,
  ));
 }

Comment: Tried code, but it's not working. Wondering if problem is in my SQL, as I'm receiving and error there.  posted question on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679010/yii-mysql-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Comment: actionCreate() function is ok. Just replace - $model->save(false);

Answer (score 1):

the save function for second model does not affect because a redirect function is called after saving the first model.

look at the wiki page.

```
if($valid)
{
    // use false parameter to disable validation
    $a->save(false);
    $b->save(false);
    // ...redirect to another page
}
```

the redirect function should be called after both models successfully saved.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This is the second model, does any of this need to be changed?  
 public function actionCreate()
 {
  $model=new SalesRepMinMarginHistory;

  // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
  // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

  if(isset($_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory']))
  {
   $model->attributes=$_POST['SalesRepMinMarginHistory'];
   if($model->save())
    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
  }

  $this->render('create',array(
   'model'=>$model,
  ));
 }

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert, but maybe you can create a trigger to effect the change? Whenever you get a new table in sales_rep_min_margin table, you can have the data dumped in sales_rep_min_margin_history table too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It seems a simple fix, and the code provided by the references I've researched would seem to do it, but I have yet to find the error.